# Is this web member in the double fan truss design problematic?

Tags: structural-engineering

[image]

Especially on lower pitched roofs, this web member is practicality horizontal. Sure seems like it's providing minimal lateral support and runs the risk of falling. Is this a poor design, and if so would adding a vertical member underneath it make it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The added vertical member will improve the stability of the end panels as it decreases the L/r ratio of the bottom chord that it is attached to, however, it does not affect the distribution of internal forces since it is a "zero force member".